# Set route template for `ActionLink` and `Url.Action`

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

Given the following code:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = "123"}, null)
```

The rendered Html code by the helper will be `/Edit?id=123`.

In case my `Action` has been decorated with a `Route` attribute or any other attribute with a template such as `HttpGet("{id}")`, the generated URL surely fails. I know that I can work this around by doing something similar to:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Edit")/@id">Edit</a>
```

However, I would like to know if there's any built-in functionality for changing the template of the URLs generated by MVC helpers, for example in order to achieve the given example.

Comment: In those cases, do you have a Route attribute on the controller?

Comment: @juunas: Yes, exactly

Comment: Could you add it to the question and show its value?

Comment: @juunas: Already there `HttpGet("{id}")`

Comment: No, I meant do you have one on the controller class? As in `[Route("[controller]")] public class HomeController { ... }`.

Comment: @juunas: No, I have the templates for my Actions only.

Answer (score -2):

If you intended for the link to be `/Edit/123`, then the route attribute must look like this:

```
[HttpGet("[action]/{id}")]
```

Currently you are trying to route to `/123`.

The placeholder `[action]` will be replaced by the action name.

Comment: You have misunderstood the question.